# What is purpose of glue command and @StepDefAnnotation in testrunner class file?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)

@CucumberOptions( plugin = {"pretty","html:target/html/automation"},
                features = {"resource/***.feature"},
                 glue={}
        )

@StepDefAnnotation()
```

How to use the StepDefAnnotation tag in cucumber framework?

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't. It's an internal Cucumber class i.e. not part of the public API.

See here for a similar reply from a Cucumber developer: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/733#issuecomment-53884424

Comment: Thanks for response!

Comment: and i think you want to use: glue = {"classpath:your.step.def.package"},